# Saving Facebook Graph Data in MYSQL database to save time legal?

Tags: mysql, facebook-graph-api

I am presently using Facebook's graph to list local events on a website, however it takes an excessive amount of time to access all the data I want to from the graph every time time the page loads [~100 events].  Using a MYSQL database to store all the events and their details (and updating the data a few times a day) cuts the page loading time down to next to nothing.

My question is whether using a database in this fashion is legal (Copyright law???), and does it abide by the Facebook Terms of Service?

Only "public" events are used, with the description, event photo,the number of people attending etc, and the gender ratio of the people attending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [Facebook API's Policy pag](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)e:

> You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in
>   order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should
>   try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any
>   rights to such data.

Comment: I remember remember reading that a long time back, only I though that caching had more to to with setting server options, not using databases.  Thanks.